# How can i set the Height of a table Cell in google docs using app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Like setWidth(), there is no setHeight() function to set a fix  height to a table cell in the google  docs.Is there any other way to go about to achieve this issue?

main idea is to stop table from overflowing into next page when an image is inserted into the table cell.

Comment: See [TableRow.setMinimumHeight()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-row#setMinimumHeight(Number))

Comment: Thanks for the help. But i want to set maximum row height not minimum. i don't want row heights to increase after certain point. Thanks

Comment: That's all there is, no maximum.